# Describing attachments for multipass rendering

Tags: c++, render, renderer, vulkan

I am trying to create a deferred renderer in vulkan with one renderpass and two sub-passes. The first one should be the geometry pass to fill the G-Buffer and the second one should be the shading pass to apply the lighting. The problem now is that I can't wrap my head around how I should describe the dependencies between the subpasses in the `VkRenderPassCreateInfo`.

The `VkRenderPassCreateInfo` has a field:

`pAttachments` points to an array of `attachmentCount` number of `VkAttachmentDescription` structures describing properties of the attachments, or `NULL` if `attachmentCount` is zero.

But the `VkSubpassDescription` has a field:

`pColorAttachments` is an array of `colorAttachmentCount` `VkAttachmentReference` structures that lists which of the render pass’s attachments will be used as color attachments in the subpass, and what layout each attachment will be in during the subpass. Each element of the array corresponds to a fragment shader output location, i.e. if the shader declared an output variable `layout(location=X)` then it uses the attachment provided in `pColorAttachments[X]`

So to my understanding the `pColorAttachments` of the `VkSubpassDescription` declare the layout of the output of each pass. So in my example, the first subpass would have 4 outputs: 1 position, 1 normal, 1 specular and 1 depth attachment. And the second subpass would have 1 output: the color which is displayed on the screen. If that is true, what is the purpose of the `pAttachments` field in the `VkRenderPassCreateInfo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Render passes define attachments; subpasses *reference* them. That's why the struct is called: `VkAttachmentReference`; it references an attachment defined by the render pass. The render pass defines attachments with an array of `VkAttachmentDescription` objects. The `VkAttachmentReference` is just an index into that array.

There is a hard limit on the number of attachments you can have in a render pass, as well as the number of attachments that an individual subpass can use.

Comment: So the renderpass specifies the total amount and type of attachments and the subpasses just reference which ones they will use. Thank you very much.

Comment: That's right. That's why, when You create a framebuffer, it's images correspond to render pass's attachments (those specified with an array of `VkAttachmentDescription` objects).